# Firewall Details Explanation

Tags: firewall

I would like to know more information about this details for a firewall:

50,000 Max. connections; 650Mbps Overall Throughput; 246,900 Packets PS

What I understood is that the firewall can accept 50k requests from one client and 246,900 packets per second. Can someone can clarify this? The same thing with 650Mbps. What I understood is the firewall can handle 650Mbp data size, which is the requests sent from the clients.

Can anyone correct me if I am wrong?

What if the client managed to overload the firewall by sending more than 650Mbp. Is the firewall going to shutdown?

Comment: Also, understand that what a vendor claims for these figures is under ideal conditions, and it is probably marketing hype that cannot necessarily be compared between vendors. Unfortunately, you can only get actual performance number for your situation from testing in your lab.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A stateful firewall has to keep some metadata about a connection (more cortectly: a session) like source and destination address,  state, NAT port etc. In a table in RAM. This always is limited by hardware. The figure is meant for all concurrent sessions or session attempts globally.

Throughput in bits per second the sum of all traffic on all ports in and out. Some vendors count inbound traffic twice as it has to leave the fw again, some don't. The more honest figure is packets per second which is limited by hatdware, clock speed and latency.

When packet size gets smaller throughput in Mbps drops but pps stay constant. HTTP can use big packet with 1500 bytes but often uses much smaller one at eg 64 bytes.

Overload can be handled in a begnin way by just dropping traffic or more dramatically by having the fw lock up or reboot. This depends on the architecture and vendor.